# Option product quantity is zero, not displaying in configurable product in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, stock, stock-status, configurable-swatches, configurable-product-options

I tried admin panel settings

> Products -> Catalog ->inventory

**Dispaly product if out of stock (yes)**. But still for configurable product of my swatch option quantity is (0) zero, that option(child) product was not displaying.

I like to display all child products it was **In-stock** and **Out-stock**

Please help to find this solution

Thanks

Comment: Please help to find the solution

Comment: click 'Advanced Inventory' then underneath the 'Manage Stock' dropdown uncheck the 'Use Config Settings' checkbox and then set it to 'No'

Comment: I had this same problem. Settings were fine. It was my template that was calling the wrong method to get the value.